# How to solve the NVIDIA driver?

Tags: pytorch

```
C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py:52: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 9010).
Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver. (Triggered internally at  ..\c10\cuda\CUDAFunctions.cpp:100.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

[image]

My system:
Windows 10
Nvidia GeForce 940 MX

Comment: Two suggestions, first, if you are planning to use 940 MX for ML, well _don't_ and second, you need to install latest NVIDIA drivers!

Comment: The question says `how to solve NVIDIA driver` - what does it even mean? Is the OP facing version mismatch? Unable to find drivers? Question needs to be more focused!

Answer (score 0):

A quick checklist to setup your ML environment with pytorch (a practitioner's advice - do them in order as in the checklist, *bindings matter*):

1. Get some [good GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) (*940 MX isn't preferable*)
2. Install [NVIDIA drivers](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/381.65/381.65-notebook-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe) (added link to v381, once installed, on Windows platform, you will get update notification!)
3. Install [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit)
4. Install [CuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/CUDNN)
5. Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)
6. [Create a conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands)
7. Install [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

You can find ample blogs over the internet that will walk you through the steps in detail.

Comment: Before downvoting, please consider, that the OP has not provided the current driver version, toolkit version, conda version, python version and pytorch version. In the absence of these details, only a generic checklist can be provided!